# SQL Server partitioning and index strategy

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, database-partitioning

I'm looking for a partitioning solution. And, obviously, I'm interested in the performance side of it. Means, not to make it too bad while benefiting maintenance time.
My question is related to one of the tables that I have. And it looks similar to

```
Id bigint IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
DatetimeFiled,
/*
    a lot of other fields
*/
```

According to the data structure and usage, it's suitable to split the table into partitions by the DatetimeFiled (classic), because I have filters by date on this table.
But I do have filters by Id as well. Moreover, I have JOINs that use the Id field as a predicate, which now benefits from its uniqueness (https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/08/performance-benefits-of-unique-indexes/).

So, I decided to use `Id ,DatetimeFiled` as `UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX`.

But I doubt will it still benefit JOINs by Id field?
And is it ok to use that kind of field order, because I saw that partitioned field is often in the first place?

Comment: Doesn't seem to make sense: as soon as you include a unique column, any other key columns are pointless. The opposite order might make sense though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a trailing clustered index column as the partition column is a common and useful approach.  You can find rows by Id by seeking the Clustered Index in each partition, and you can find rows by DatetimeFiled through partition elimination.